# Avoid weird effect on slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my app I am getting a very ugly side effect for using `slideDown()`. When clicking the element a piece of content is appended to an ancestor. The side effect is that the clicked button jumps to the right and the two in the left move a bit two. I just want the button group to stay still.

Here it is, just click the yellow refresh button: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0m4qq484/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#counter-offer', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var thiz = $(this);
    var element = thiz.closest('#negotiation-buttons').find('div#counter-offer-form-container')
    $.get('/negotiation/counter_offer_form', $(this).find('form').serialize(), function(data) {
        if (element.length) {
            element.slideUp('200', function() {
                element.remove();
            });
        }  else {
            thiz.closest('#negotiation-buttons').append(data['form']).
            find('#counter-offer-form-container').hide().slideDown(400);
        }
    });
});
```

I don't know how to avoid that. Any ideas?

Comment: Please include the code in the question itself.

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/0m4qq484/1/

Comment: no, you just removed the wrapping containers and also the input makes a weird effect...

Comment: Your wrapper width is changing and you're using dynamic columns size so it's normal that your button position changes

Comment: yeah but I am using bootstrap grid system which uses 12 grids, and the buttons take 8+4=12 so what's appended right after them is going to be in another "line". I don't understand why it's messing with what's above it. I tried wrapping the buttons in another div with the 12 grids class but I got the same results.

Comment: your row length is relative to your #negotiation-buttons container and this container's width is varying. That's why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to set a fixed size container

```
#negotiation-buttons {
    width: 300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0m4qq484/5/